# How does Kotlin allow you to instantiate an interface like this? I don't understand this

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin and I'm really confused about this piece of code ([source](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#initialize)):

```kotlin
private val purchasesUpdatedListener = PurchasesUpdatedListener { billingResult, purchases ->
       // To be implemented in a later section.
}
```

`PurchasesUpdatedListener` is an [interface](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/PurchasesUpdatedListener) and has one abstract function `onPurchasesUpdated`.

In the snippet above, we never create the class implementing this interface, we don't even say we're overriding the abstract function. But somehow, this one line seems to be doing everything like magic.

I have 2 questions:

1. What is going on here and how should I understand it if I'm coming from a java background?
2. Where can I learn more about these shortcuts? I looked at kotlinlang.org and couldn't find anything about this there.

Comment: see this: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/fun-interfaces.html#sam-conversions

Comment: @SarthakMittal Oh I didn't see that, thanks for sharing. So this is specific to functional interfaces only. I can't do this if the interface has more than one function?

Comment: exactly @Plasty! :)

Comment: @SarthakMittal Thank you! If you can post your comment as an answer I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is functional interface in kotlin, also called SAM(single abstract method) interface.

So, as long as you have a single abstract method and you mark your interface with `fun` keyword:

```
fun interface FunInterface {
   fun isFun(): Boolean
}
```

You can implement it anonymously like this:

```
val funImpl = FunInterface { /* return Boolean */ }
```

Otherwise the common way to subclass classes/interfaces anonymously is by using the `object` keyword:

```
val funImpl = object : FunInterface {
   override fun isFun(): Boolean {
       /* return Boolean */
   }
}
```

See this for more info: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/fun-interfaces.html