# kotlin multiple methods(?) syntax

Tags: kotlin, spring-security

I am exploring Spring Security and found a code snippet in the official Spring docs which I am not able to interpret, and Idea shows it as syntactically incorrect

```
@Bean
open fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
   http {
        authorizeRequests {
            authorize(anyRequest, authenticated)
        }
       formLogin { }
       httpBasic { }
    }
    return http.build()
}
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/kotlin.html

can anyone give me a hint, how to parse that? The closest Kotlin syntax I am aware of is "multiple methods with" statement, but it is something different.

Also, terms anyRequest and authenticated look undeclared/unbound...

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/idioms.html#call-multiple-methods-on-an-object-instance-with

Comment: Also, [functional (SAM) interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75919133/how-does-kotlin-allow-you-to-instantiate-an-interface-like-this-i-dont-underst) might be involved here.

Comment: Ok, it is Kotlin DSL.

The doc 

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/kotlin.html

refers to it, but the code sample was reverted to traditional code 

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/blob/main/servlet/spring-boot/kotlin/hello-security/src/main/kotlin/org/springframework/security/samples/config/SecurityConfig.kt


https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/blob/main/servlet/spring-boot/kotlin/hello-security/src/main/kotlin/org/springframework/security/samples/config/SecurityConfig.kt

Comment: It (Kotlin Spring Security DSL) was introduced here https://spring.io/blog/2020/03/04/spring-tips-kotlin-and-spring-security

Comment: Here is when security samples switched from Kotlin DLS https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/commit/bce2126fd185b01393c93d29742e72baa74676b8?diff=split#diff-4ff561f335651f6dee5b003831df5fd35cc6cf933479d4664209eff882e7265b

Answer (score 0):

There are two things in here that could be involved.

### Calling functions with lambda parameters

Calling a function/contructor with a lambda `{ }` works if the last argument of that function allows a lambda function to be passed. All of the following are equivalent:

```kotlin
//normal lambda as parameter
function({...})
//last argument lambda outside of parentheses
function() {...}
//no parentheses for "better" readability
function {...}
```

### Functional interfaces

Kotlin allows single-function interfaces, also called Single Abstract Methods. See [the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/fun-interfaces.html#sam-conversions). With this, you can declare a function without giving an implementation, useful for libraries.

Comment: Instead of functional interfaces, these might be defined as Kotlin higher order functions with functional type parameters. Not sure since I don't use Spring.